# Replace pairs of lines in XML document using Sed (or something BASH-like) and convert to CSV

Tags: xml, bash, csv, sed, sh

I have a pdf document which I've converted to an XML document (to make it a bit easier to work with), and I need to strip out most of the data and change pairs of lines into csv format. Here's what I have in my XML:

```
<text top="231" left="75" width="154" height="11" font="2">JGD0002250185412827</text>
<text top="231" left="288" width="122" height="11" font="2">CODE99876</text>
<text top="231" left="482" width="8" height="11" font="2">1</text>
<text top="231" left="555" width="57" height="11" font="2">IP65 5LK</text>
<text top="231" left="696" width="89" height="11" font="2">Malcolm Montgomery</text>
<text top="252" left="75" width="154" height="11" font="2">JGD0012564109019827</text>
<text top="252" left="288" width="122" height="11" font="2">CODE4674</text>
<text top="252" left="482" width="8" height="11" font="2">1</text>
<text top="252" left="551" width="65" height="11" font="2">CV98 3LN</text>
<text top="252" left="680" width="121" height="11" font="2">WILLIAM SHATNER</text>
```

I need to get something like the following from that:

```
"CODE99876","JGD0002250185412827","IP65 5LK"
"CODE4674","JGD0012564109019827","CV98 3LN"
```

I'm assuming it's possible, but so far no luck (disaster in fact, my outputs have just looks like an angry child's gone to town on a bucket of alphabetti-spaghetti).

Comment: How about the other data? And it seems like "IP65 5LK" in the original text comes after CODE99876 which comes after JGD0002250185412827. Is that correct? How do you choose which data to include?

Comment: That's correct, in the csv it doesn't matter too much how it's ordered, as long as the relevant bits are in the same row of the csv. It's a large file, and I need all the sections of data in the csv (on new rows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' -v OFS='","' '{idx=NR%5; a[idx]=$3} !idx{print "\"" a[2], a[1], a[4] "\""}' file
"CODE99876","JGD0002250185412827","IP65 5LK"
"CODE4674","JGD0012564109019827","CV98 3LN"
```

Answer (score 2):

This works as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    if (/<text .*<\/text>/) {
        i = ++vr % 5
        if (i == 0) {
            print "\"" a[2] "\",\"" a[1] "\",\"" a[4] "\""
        } else {
            sub(/<\/text>.*/, "")
            sub(/.*<text .*>/, "")
            a[i] = $0
        }
    }
}
```